# Question related to Milnor's proof of the hairyball theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I am trying to understand Milnor's proof of the Hairy Ball Theorem (here's the proof I am trying to read: http://people.ucsc.edu/~lewis/Math208/hairyball.pdf). In lemma 1, he first considers the case that the compact set $A\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is a cube and proves that given $x,y \in A$, there exists a Lipschitz constant $c$ such that $||v(x)-v(y)||\leq c||x-y||$ and I understand that. But then he comments that any in case $A$ is abitrary and $x,y$ are not in the same cube, then we can still choose a Lipschitz constant $c$ but I don't see how this follows. Thanks!

---

I could only prove that $f(x,y)$ is continuous on compact $J=A\times A-\cup(I_{\alpha}\times I_{\alpha})$ where $I_{\alpha}$ are open cubes.
(Since $I_{\alpha}$s are open , is their union and so J is closed. Also, $\mathbb{R^n}$ is compact, so $J\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ is compact. Also, given $(x_k,y_k)$ converging to $(x,y)$, we have $x_k\to x$ and $y_k\to y$ and so $(x_k-y_k)$ goes to $(x-y)$ and thus $||(x_k-y_k)||$ goes to $||(x-y)||$(using the continuity of the norm function). So, $f$ attains max and min on $A$ but that's all I could salvage.

Comment: As $(x,y)$ varies over $J$ there is an upper bound $M$ to $||\nu(x)-\nu(y)||$ and a positive lower bound $m$ to $||x-y||$. Take $c=M/m$.

Comment: Thanks for the link, BTW, I did not know about this paper of Milnor.

Comment: @LeeMosher. Thank you very much. I am a bit short on sleep, so please excuse my lack of clarity in thought) but how does Milnor infer that $w\not= 0$?

Comment: Because $J$ is a compact subspace of $A \times A$, so the minimum of $||x-y||$ is attained at some $(x,y) \in J$. But $J$ is disjoint from the diagonal --- because each $x \in A$ is contained in some $I_\alpha$ and so $(x,x) \in I_\alpha \times I_\alpha$ which is disjoint from $J$ --- and so that minimum is positive.

Comment: @LeeMosher, sorry I think we are referring to two different things. I understood your initial comments. I was referring to $w$ as defined on $S^{n-1}$ by $w=p-(p\cdot u)u$ in theorem 1' on page 3.

Comment: I think this works. $|w|\ge |p|-|(p.u)u|>|p|-m/2$. Now, $|p|=|v-(v-p)|\ge |v|-|v-p|>m-m/2=m/2$ so $|w|>0$.